# Realm doesn't add a iterable

Tags: android, realm

I tried to add Iterable to the Realm, but it doesn't work.

```
public List<Country> add (List<Country> countries){
            db.executeTransaction(new Realm.Transaction() {
                @Override
                public void execute(Realm realm) {
                        realm.copyToRealmOrUpdate(countries);
                }
            });
            return  countries;
        }
```

When i use to add to realm to a single object it works, what am I doing wrong?

```
public Country add (Country country){
    db.executeTransaction(new Realm.Transaction() {
        @Override
        public void execute(Realm realm) {
            realm.copyToRealm(country);
        }
    });
    return  country;
}
```

It's my model i tried many variants with a primary key, but it steel doesn't work :(

```
public class City extends RealmObject {

    @Required
    String name;


    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

I rewrite my programm, and adding in to the Realm does not work at all.
That's how I initializing.

```
public class AppGeo extends Application {
    private static AppGeo instance;
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        Realm.init(this);
        RealmConfiguration config = new RealmConfiguration.Builder()
                .name("geoapp.realm")
                .schemaVersion(1)
                .deleteRealmIfMigrationNeeded()
                .modules(new RealmModule())
                .build();
        Realm.setDefaultConfiguration(config);
    instance = this;
    }

    public static AppGeo getInstance(){
        return instance;
    }
}
```

The method that I am calling

```
@Override
public void primaryInit(onGetAllCountryCallback callback) {
    final Realm realmConnection = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
    if(realmConnection.isEmpty()){
        WebService webService = WebService.getInstace(AppGeo.getInstance());
        Observable.defer(() -> Observable.just(webService.getCountriesInformation()))
                .map(Parser::countriesParser)
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe(new Subscriber<List<Country>>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCompleted() {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(Throwable e) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onNext(List<Country> countries) {
                        callback.onSuccess(countries);
                        realmConnection.executeTransaction(realm -> realmConnection.copyToRealmOrUpdate(countries));

                    }
                });

    }
    else {
        findAll(callback);
    }
    realmConnection.close();
}
```

Comment: The above should work. What makes you say it doesn't?

Comment: Add code for `Country`. Also check your country collection for correct primary keys.